# Which of Drupal multisite takes most resources?

Tags: performance, drupal-7

My server gets out of RAM frequently. 
There is approximately 40 (**Drupal 7**) sites in multisite installation. Caching is enabled on all of them. 
Is there any way how to find out which one takes the most resources?

Answer (score 0):

it's good question, i think you can try several solution :

1 - https://www.drupal.org/project/site_audit, it can be helpful

2 - Watch on server with command lines , CPU , RAM , and HTTPD usage : http://www.tecmint.com/command-line-tools-to-monitor-linux-performance/

3 - NOT FREE solution : http://newrelic.com/php/drupal

Enjoy and let us know if of those solution helps to you